# Does pragmapack() in C programming have any usage apart from structure packing?

Tags: c, generic-programming, structure-packing

While I'm on an interview the interviewer asked me are there any other usage of pragmapack() in C apart from structure packing? So I answered that I don't know apart from structure packing. So are there any other usage of it?

Comment: To my knowledge it packs elements of structures, unions, and, in C++, class members.

Comment: What do you mean by "pragmapack()"?

Comment: Did the interviewer frown? Make a note? Laugh dismissively? In other words: why would you think your answer was wrong? Did you check the documentation for your compiler?

Comment: Could it have been `#pragma pack`, i.e., was it a spoken question?

Comment: Yes.  I suppose you could have followed up by explaining why non-standard structure packing might be useful.  Knowledge they really want to test you on.

Answer (score 0):

```
#pragma pack(size)
```

is a preprocessor directive used for altering structure padding schemes. Usually a structure adds padding bytes between it's members to speed up the memory fetch operations.
the number of padding bytes it used is depends on machine architecture. 
for example,

```
struct sample {
    int a;
    char b;
    int c;
};
```

When we see the above structure it requires only 9 bytes ( 4 + 1 + 4) to hold members a, b and c, but for a 32 bit architecture, a variable of this structure takes 16 bytes (4 + 4 + 4) of memory. even though char b only requires 1 byte, it takes 4 bytes 1 for storing value of b and other three as padding bytes.

```
padding_size = (word_size of machine architecture > highest sized structure member datatype's size) ? highest sized structure member datatype's size : word_size of machine architecture;
```

we can forcefully assign padding size using preprocessor directive `#pragma pack(size)` , `size` should be a power of 2 less than the word_size of machine architecture.

If we use like

```
#pragma pack(1)
```

for the above structure then the total amount of memory required for holding a variable of type `struct sample` will be (4 + 1 + 4) 9 bytes.